# If matrix A is invertible, is it diagonalizable as well?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, diagonalization

If a matrix A is invertible, then it is diagonalizable. Is it true or false?

Comment: True if $A$ is $1\times 1$.

Comment: @vadim123 It is somewhat meaningless to talk about diagonalizability in $1\times 1$ though... everything is diagonal in $1\times 1$.

Answer (score 31):

It is false. Consider $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I love minimal counterexamples.