# A demonstration on diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Determine the truth or falsity of the following proposition.

> If $A$ is a square matrix of order $n$ and is invertible, then $A$ is  diagonalizable.

This proposition is false. For example, the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

is invertible, but not diagonalizable. Since it has only a single eigenspace $E_{\lambda =1}=\textrm{span}\left \{ \left ( 0,1 \right ) \right \}$.

How to demonstrate that falsehood in general?

Comment: what do you mean by do not find to demonstrate the falsehood in general?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If matrix A is invertible, is it diagonalizable as well?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604415/if-matrix-a-is-invertible-is-it-diagonalizable-as-well)

Comment: For a general $n$, just consider $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&1}\oplus0$.

Answer (score 0):

> But I do not find to demonstrate that falsehood in general.

I don't think there is a way to demonstrate this in general. Such statements are considered *false*, so long as you can provide a case that the given condition is wrong.

> If A is a square matrix of order n is invertible, then A is diagonalizable

The above statement is *false*, because there are square matrices that don't match that condition such as:

$\left ( \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1
\end{matrix} \right )$,
$\left ( \begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right )$
etc...

Answer (score 0):

Although your example is enough to disprove the statement, here is an example for any $n\in \mathbb N$ 
$$\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array}{cc|c|c|c|c}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\0 & 1 &0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 1\end{array}\end{pmatrix}$$

The matrix is an identity matrix except that $a_{12}$ is equal to $1$, while not being diagonalizable.